# Increasing Timeout Values in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a JSON service that I'm exposing via ASP.NET MVC 3. This service is exposed as an Action on a Controller. I can successfully call the action. However, occasionally, the action takes too long to complete. Because of that, my caller fails due to a timeout. My question is, how do I change the timeout threshold's in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the calling agent that is throwing the timeout exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need do some task that you know can take a little while would be nice use AsyncControllers, and you can set diferent timeout betwen actions

for example

```
[AsyncTimeout(3000)] //timeout in miliseconds
public void DoTaskAsync(){

//something that takes a long time
 AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = contentresult; //Contentresult is your data result of process

}
public ActionResult DoTaskCompleted(String result){
   return json(result);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx#Y4400 for details...

otherwise... `HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 3000;`

Comment: Are there any settings I can make in the web.config to handle this globally?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is timing out.  If it's just the server response, I believe you can set it in the controller itself (in seconds):

```
HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = XXX;
```

If it's something like the session or authentication timing out you will need to extend those values.